# Execute SAS macro for many parameters

Tags: sql, macros, sas

I use the following code to insert rows to the table:

```sql
proc sql;
    create table business_keys as
    select name, memname 
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where 1=0;
quit;

%macro insert(list);
   proc sql;
     %do i=1 %to &max;
         %let val = %scan(&list,&i); 
            insert into business_keys
            select distinct name, memname 
            from sashelp.vcolumn 
            where upcase(memname) = "&list" 
              and upcase(name) like '%_ZRODLO_ID%' 
              and length(name) = 12;
        %end;
    quit;
%mend;

%insert(&name1);
```

Now it inserts me the same row many `&max` times.

I have to execute it for all macro variables (&name#), not only for `&name1`. **How I can pass all variables at the same time?** In principle, I want to loop through all of these table names:

```
%insert(&name1-&name&max)
```

> %name1 = PEOPLE, %name2 = CREDITS, ... %name%max = ANY_TABLE_NAME

Where &name# is table name and &max is number of tables.

Comment: Firstly you should define "max" variable

Comment: I did it. In this case 48.

Comment: Let me ask you some questions if I understand this correct: You have several macrovariables name1-to namex which have exactly *one* value? You know the number of these variables in your macrovariable max, and now you want to insert vor every value a row with memname=value of each macrovariable? The %let val line was just a test from you and has no meaning for what you want to archive?

Comment: Yes, I have several macrovariables (name1-name&max) with one string values (these are table names). I know value of max (I get it from another query) and I want to insert for every value (name#) a row with memname=name3 (so this code should insert &max rows containing: name, memname). I tried to use 'The %let val line ' to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, now i understand what you want to do, it is actually quite simple:

```
%macro insert;
proc sql;
    %do i=1 %to &max; 
            insert into business_keys
            select distinct name, memname 
            from sashelp.vcolumn 
            where upcase(memname) = upcase("&&name&i") and upcase(name) like '%_ZRODLO_ID%' and length(name) = 12;
    %end;
quit;
%mend;
%insert;
```

&&name&i resolves to &name1\&name2...\&namex which resolves to PEOPLE\CREDITS...\ANY_TABLE_NAME depending on i.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to pass a "macro array" to your macro to process. Where by "macro array" I mean a series of macro variables that all consist of a base name and a numeric suffix.  Like NAME1, NAME2, etc.  It would be easier to do that by passing two parameters to your macro. One for the basename of the array and one for the upper limit (or max) index.

```
%macro insert(basename,max);
  %local i;
  ...
  %do i=1 %to &max ;
    ... &&basename&i ...
  %end;
  ...
%mend insert;
```

So you might call the macro like this:

```
%let name1=PEOPLE;
%let name2=CREDITS;
%insert(NAME,2);
```

Personally I would avoid the macro array and instead store the list in a single macro variable.  If the list is just SAS names (datasets, libraries, variables, formats, etc.) then just use space for the delimiter. If it is something like labels that could include spaces then use some other character like `|` for the delimiter.  Then your macro would look more like this.

```
%macro insert(memlist);
  %local i;
  ...
  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&memlist,%str( ))) ;
    ... %scan(&memlist,&i,%str( )) ...
  %end;
  ...
%mend insert;
```

So you might call the macro like this:

```
%insert(PEOPLE CREDITS);
```

Answer (score 1):

If **list** looks like *PEOPLE,CREDITS,...,ANY_TABLE_NAME*
you should define **max** variable as following:

```
%let max = %sysfunc(countw(&list,',')).
```

You will know the number of iterations.

```
%macro insert(list);

%let max = %sysfunc(countw(&list,',')).

proc sql;
    %do i=1 %to &max;
        %let val = %scan(&list,&i);
            insert into business_keys
            select distinct name, memname 
            from sashelp.vcolumn 
            where upcase(memname) = "&val" and upcase(name) like '%_ZRODLO_ID%' and length(name) = 12;
    %end;
quit;
%mend;
```

Comment: I don't have list of these variables (tables) but separated macro variables (&name#) for each tables.

Comment: In your code you don't use variable val which contains condition for select query